# 64 bit hash table in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, hash, stl, hashtable

I need a hash table which uses 64 bit as its hash.

To make it clearer, `unordered_set` receives a template argument `Hash` which is a functor that takes an argument of type `Key` and return a 32 bit unsigned integer.

I need something similar only it should take a template argument `Hash` which is a functor that takes an argument of type `Key` and return a 64 bit unsigned integer.

Does anyone know of such a container (perferbly on a header only library like STL)?

Comment: Why? With most kinds of hash table, including the ones allowed as `unordered_set` implementation (IIRC and it prescribes buckets), any bits beyond the table size rounded up to a power of two are lost. So you'd need more than 4 billion keys for the extra bits to matter.

Comment: Unless you describe why you need a 64-bit hash result, and why you feel 32-bit won't suffice, it's difficult to suggest any alternatives. Anyway, [`std::hash::operator()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash/operator%28%29) returns a `size_t`, which should be 64-bit if you compile using a 64-bit compiler.

Comment: Actually, this is incorect, size_t is not 64 bit, and I am compiling with a 64 bit compiler. Try sizeof(size_t) and you'll see. int64_t is... Anyways many problems can be solved efficiently by using hash results. For example: Find an algorithm to unite all words that use the same letters in a dictonery, one solution will be to insert them into a hash table where the hash is done by seting a bit for each letter that is present in the word. You might say that on this example only 26 bits are necessary, but what if I consider Upper case letters different from lower case?

Comment: @buc030 The size of a hash value depends on the number of entries in the hash table and not on the length of the data being hashed.  If you are hashing every sentence in a novel, a 32-bit key is plenty because there are lots less that 4 billion sentences in any reasonable novel.

Comment: Thanks for the response guys, but brian beuning: the size of the hash value is constant. If you mean 'the size I need', then I must disagree, because I need to seperate a lot of values into buckets. ofcourse it is possible to map all words in a novel into one of the 32 bits integers, but if you want to map it fast, it is much more convenient to have 64 bit hashes. See my comment above, it descibes an example...

Comment: @buc030 `size_t` is usually 64-bit when you compile 64-bit binaries; see [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=e916416a316812acab3046fa5a681fc1-6e9f1f680880347f6708b805c806db62) for example. If you're using a 64-bit OS, make sure your compiler is building 64-bit binaries as well.

Comment: You example hash function (1 bit for each letter present) is horrible and would lead to a high number of hash collisions. Have you actually measured the performance of `std::unordered_set` and found an issue that lead to this question?

Comment: You guys don't know what you are talking about, and then you vote down so people that do know what they are talking about won't address this question!?  @Blastfurnace , by saying "You example hash function is horrible" you ilustrate you either don't understand other usage to hash tables rather than fast look-up, either you didn't even read the whole example through.

Comment: @Blastfurnace, You are right, no point of getting angry, I apologize. it just very upsetting when everyone who replies focus on trying to show you that you don't know what you want, instead of trying to answer the question. When you reply like that other people who might have different perspective might not take the question seriously.

Comment: What compiler and options are you using? All of gcc, clang, and MSVC use a 64-bit `size_t` when doing a x64 build. I just checked MSVC and you can see that clang does at the link in Praetorian's comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a popular hash function for strings

```
size_t hash( const char * string )
{
    size_t result = 0;
    while( *string != 0 ) {
        result = result * 31 + *string++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Making up new hash functions is a popular past time for computer people, so I am not saying this is the best.
But the point is the result type does not need to be bigger to handle bigger strings.